# Combine the properties of two CSS classes with a filter attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To sum up the effects of the filter property we have to do as for this 'union class.'

```
.class1{filter:brightness(125%);}
.class2{filter:blur(5px);}
.unionClass{filter:brightness(125%) blur(5px);}
```

But what if the code is written this way?

```
//i want this
<p class="class1 class2">Hello</p>
//instead of
<p class="unionClass">Hello</p>
```

In the first example as a result we would only apply the class2 class, so filter class1 class property will be lost; While in the second the 'unionClass' class will display all the united properties, as they are already contained in it.
I would like to see the same effect by writing 'class = "class1 class2' ', how can i do it? Does css not have a right way? So with javascript what would be the right way?

Comment: @charlietfl: You sure about that? It's the same property (`filter`), not a different property. In my experiments, it works as the OP says (I was kind of hoping it would merge them, but no): https://jsfiddle.net/h48d99bp/ (I had to use `drop-shadow` rather than `brightness`; I couldn't see the `brightness` difference.)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case, firefox mozilla applies both, but the first is ignored and does not apply it.

Comment: Sounds like a case for Less or Sass, because I bet you're going to have to duplicate those styles in a combined rule.

Comment: When splitted like that, the latter will overwrite the former, as it will with any other property

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I asked, just because I'm trying to avoid the creation of additional classes.

Comment: @User: Well, as LGSon pointed out in a deleted answer, you don't have to add *classes*, just styling blocks. You don't need `.unionClass { ... }`, just `.class1.class2 { ... }`. But it does still require repeating the styling blocks, hence my note about Less or Sass.

Comment: @User Updated my answer with a script sample...to show how that could look like

Comment: @LGSon Thanks, really helpful. I forgot: I had decided to implement a similar solution for real, you did anticipate me though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible to do using CSS.

When splitt'd like that, the latter will overwrite the former, as it will with any other property.

From a *maintenance* and *easy-to-read* perspective it could be interesting to do something like this

```
.fil-bright-125 {
  filter:brightness(125%);
}

.fil-blur-5 {
  filter:blur(5px);
}

.fil-bright-125.fil-blur-5 {
  filter:brightness(125%) blur(5px);
}
```

And then use it like this

```css
p {
  color: blue;
  background: yellow;
}

.fil-bright-175 {
  filter:brightness(175%);
}

.fil-blur-1 {
  filter:blur(1px);
}

.fil-bright-175.fil-blur-1 {
  filter:brightness(175%) blur(1px);
}
```

```html
<p class="fil-bright-175">I am bright</p>

<p class="fil-blur-1">I am blurry</p>

<p class="fil-bright-175 fil-blur-1">I am bright and blurry</p>
```

---

Updated

For completeness, here is a version using script, which look up the classes in the style sheet and then creates a new, where they are combined.

Compared with the above, I don't find the below more maintainable, almost the opposite actually.

*Note, this script can of course be optimized, though the purpose was to show a sample of how it could be done using script*

```js
(function(d, w) {
  w.addEventListener("load", function() {

    function getStyle(cls) {
      var classes = d.styleSheets[0].rules || d.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
      var val = '';
      for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < cls.length; y++) {
          if (classes[x].selectorText == cls[y]) {
            val += ' ' + ((classes[x].cssText) ? classes[x].cssText : classes[x].style.cssText).split('filter')[1].replace(/[:;} ]/g, '');
          }
        }
      }
      return val;
    }
    var val = getStyle(['.fil-bright-175','.fil-blur-1']);
    val = '.fil-bright-175.fil-blur-1 {filter:' + val + '}';

    var head = d.head || d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        style = d.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet) {
      style.styleSheet.cssText = val;
    } else {
      style.appendChild(d.createTextNode(val));
    }
    head.appendChild(style);

  }, false);
}(document, window));
```

```css
p {
  color: blue;
  background: yellow;
}
.fil-bright-175 {
  filter: brightness(175%);
}
.fil-blur-1 {
  filter: blur(1px);
}
```

```html
<p class="fil-bright-175">I am bright</p>

<p class="fil-blur-1">I am blurry</p>

<p class="fil-bright-175 fil-blur-1">I am bright and blurry</p>
```

Comment: But in pure CSS, I don't think there's a way around that. Some meta-CSS things (Less, Sass) would make it possible to at least avoid repeating the actual values.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, there is't. OP also asked if with script, so I am about to suggest one with that.